# Filter attributes from an object

Tags: reactjs

Basically, I have one object that looks like this:

```
MainObject:{
   Object1: {
      Factory:{
         total: int
         today: int
      }
      Group:{
         total: int
         today: int
      }
      Sector:{
         total: int
         today: int
      }
   }
   Object2: {
      Factory:{
         total: int
         today: int
      }
      Group:{
         total: int
         today: int
      }
      Sector:{
         total: int
         today: int
      }
   }
.
.
.
}
```

How can I do a filter or mapping or something, that let me format it to something like:

```
MainObject:{
   Object1: {
      Variable1:{
         Variable2: int
   }
   Object2: {
      Variable1:{
         Variable2: int
      }
   }
.
.
.
}
```

Where `Variable1` is a variable I can hardcode being it either `Factory, Group or Sector` and `Variable2` is either `total or today`.
Important to note that is an object, and not an array of objects.

Comment: could you give some sample dataset so we can working on it and help you

Comment: How can I share a sample dataset through here? Being honest, is not really more that what I already set in the first sample of code. Just replacing number with an int should do the work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution that will reduce the entries of the MainObject and keep only the specified variables for the deeper objects.

```js
const myobj={MainObject:{Object1:{Factory:{total:1,today:2},Group:{total:3,today:4},Sector:{total:5,today:6}},Object2:{Factory:{total:7,today:8},Group:{total:9,today:10},Sector:{total:11,today:12}}}};

const Variable1 = 'Group';
const Variable2 = 'today';

const updatedObject = {
  MainObject: Object.entries(myobj.MainObject).reduce((main, [key, value]) => ({
    ...main,
    [key]: {
      [Variable1]: {
        [Variable2]: value[Variable1][Variable2]
      }
    }
  }), {})
}

console.log(updatedObject);
```

Comment: This is working perfectly and is doing exactly what I wanted it to do!! Thanks a lot for this answer!

Answer (score 0):

You can create an array containing the keys of an object using a recursive function and the `Object.keys` method. Then, use the `reduce` method to reconstruct the object, only retaining the desired keys and values.

This may not be the solution to your problem, but it should provide you with a starting point.

```
function filterObj<T extends object>(
  obj: Partial<T>,
  keyToKeep: keyof T
): Partial<T> {
  return Object.keys(obj).reduce((acc, key) => {
    const value = obj[key as keyof T];
    if (key === keyToKeep) return { ...acc, [key]: value };
    else if (typeof value === 'object' && value !== null && value !== undefined)
      return { ...acc, [key]: filterObj(value as Partial<T>, keyToKeep) };

    return acc;
  }, {});
}
```